# Django-filter field not showing after adding lookup expressions - django-filter lib

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter

I'm trying to implement a search field for my website, I decide to use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#declaring-filters)

I was able to create a search field and search the records by typing the exact record name in the search field. (default it provides `exact` field lookup) And it worked fine.
[image: before]

Then I decide to add more field lookup so the search experience improves. But after adding some field lookups the search form field stopped appearing in the template.
[image]

I go through the documentation couple of times and also tried to google the issue but unable to solve it.

Test: By the way, hard cording the field lookups(`icontains`) to the queryset worked. And also the query set works fine.

So here's my context processor which handles the search field(search field is in the `base.html`)

**context_processor.py**

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.shortcuts import render
from store.filters import ProductFilter
from store.models import Product, ProductImage, Wishlist


def include_search_bar(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.order_by('name').prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'productimage_set',
            ProductImage.objects.filter(place='Main Product Image'),
            to_attr='main_image'
        ),
    )
    product_filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    products = product_filter.qs

    context = {
        'product_filter': product_filter,
        'products': products,
    }

    return context
```

**filters.py**

import django_filters
from .models import Product

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {  
            'name':['icontains']
        }
        # fields = ['name'] worked fine
```

**base.html**

```
<form class="form-inline d-flex active-pink md-form form-sm mr-3" method="get" id="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        {% render_field product_filter.form.name class="form-control form-control-sm" %}
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button type="submit" class="input-group-text btn fa fa-search" id="inputGroupPrepend2"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: With `'name': ['icontains']`, you filter with `name__icontains`, so the name of the search field (in the HTML form) should be `name__icontains`.

Comment: what if I used multiple field lookups?

Comment: then the names of the fields are `name__icontains`, `name__istartswith`, etc. so each time a combination of the field name and the lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `'name': ['icontains']`, you filter with `name__icontains`, so the name of the search field (in the HTML form) should be `name__icontains`:

```
{% render_field product_filter.form.name__icontains class="form-control form-control-sm" %}
```